# Compile redis with additional lua libs

Tags: c, lua, makefile, redis

There is a similar question on ServerFault about it: https://serverfault.com/questions/608704/installing-additional-lua-modules-into-redis

When one compiles redis from the sources, it seems possible to add lua libraries as there is a makefile available in /deps/lua.

However, this file has changed with new versions of redis (I am using 2.8.x) and the answer from serverfault no longer works.

Is there an easy way (for not very efficient people at C and make like me) to compile redis with additional lua libraries?

Comment: Try what the answer to the linked question says... that would be a start. It doesn't really require any C knowledge at all, just move a couple of files and change 1 `#include` and 1 line in a make file... that's it

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the makefile has changed since. But I'll try something for sure. I'll put a clear answer if it works. I find that it is an interesting question for all redis users.